# Issues Parsing JSON "None" with jsonlite

Tags: r, json, tidyverse, jsonlite

I am trying to read in some data from the UK covid dashboard on vaccination data that encodes some of the data as JSON within a csv file. (Download link is [here](https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=England&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22vaccinationsAgeDemographics%22:%22vaccinationsAgeDemographics%22%7D&format=csv)) from the Vaccination uptake, by vaccination date age demographics on the page (https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/vaccinations?areaType=nation&areaName=England). The issue raised is that my code no longer successfully expands the JSON data into a data.frame. This seems to be a parsing issue when the data runs into a None object.

My code reads in the data as follows (this code was successful on the data downloaded on 2021-11-25, but failed with the 2021-12-02 data). The code below fails on the fromJSON command which now errors when it reaches a "Arg": None claiming a lexical error. The error message is shown below the code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

#! Read in the latest national dashboard data
df <- read_csv("<filepath>")

df |> 
  mutate(vaccinationsAgeDemographics = map(vaccinationsAgeDemographics, ~fromJSON(. |> str_replace_all("'", "\"")))) |> 
  unnest(cols = c(vaccinationsAgeDemographics))
```

```sh
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `vaccinationsAgeDemographics`.
i `vaccinationsAgeDemographics = map(...)`.
x lexical error: invalid char in json text.
          yVaccinationDatePercentage": None}, {"age": "16_17", "Vaccin
                     (right here) ------^
```

A simplified test line would be as follows:

```r
fromJSON(df$vaccinationsAgeDemographics[1] |> str_replace_all("'", "\""))
```

which raises the similar error:

```sh
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
          yVaccinationDatePercentage": None}, {"age": "16_17", "Vaccin
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: As a quick fix I have just replaced these values in the string to something jsonlite can handle but this seems suboptimal now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue as the possible json mappings are discussed in the jsonlite docs here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-mapping.pdf

With foreknowledge that the data is intended to be numeric type and that None is not contained in any of the indicator names we can replace the `None` string with an `"NA"` using the following code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

df <- read_csv("C:\\Users\\joel.kandiah\\Downloads\\data_2021-Dec-02.csv")

fromJSON(df$vaccinationsAgeDemographics[1] |> str_replace_all("'", "\"") |> str_replace_all("None", "\"NA\""))
```